# In Thunderbird 17.0.6, how do I remove the [GMail] folders?

Tags: thunderbird

Currently, my GMail is linked on Thunderbird. I have already gone to `Account Settings > Copies & Folders` but the default folders are still there. So now I have 2 Drafts, 2 Sent, 2 Trash and 2 Junk folders. One is on the main inbox while the others are in [GMail] folder. I want to hide those and map them to the actual folders instead. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Flat Folder Tree](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/flat-folder-tree) add-on.

Comment: I did that and it did hide the [GMail] folder but now I'm stuck with multiple drafts and spam folder. How do I hide them? http://i.stack.imgur.com/VqDuo.png

Comment: Hum... I admit I am not sure how you should handle this... I think that it may be simpler to delete your current Imap account and to recreate it again...